# Android - sharing files between applications

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been trying to find different ways to share files between apps in Android. I found the [file sharing](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html) and [camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorials, wherein file is shared from owner apps' private directory and via the sd card, respectively.

I observe (from the first link) that the way to achieve it is to use `Intent.setFlags` and the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, but in the tutorial, `Intent.setFlags` API is being used in the receiver app. More specifically ,

App 1 sends request to App 2 ->

App 2 uses `setResult` to `return Intent` with `URI permissions`

In the second link,

App 1 creates a file in the sd card storage and passes it to the camera for writing.

If we look at the following picture ..

[image]

This is a typical example of how users use Android, e.g. the attachment in the email needs to be signed and is passed around between apps by the user.

What I want to ask is whether it is possible to use `URI permissions with an Intent` when `sending a Intent` to a second app, `instead` of using `in the app receiving the Intent` ?

More specifically, `can URI permissions be used` when using APIs like `startActivity` or `startService` ?

I ask this because, for e.g., when sending an intent to a second app (considering implicit intent), the intent fields (data, action, category) will be set to match the intent filter of the app that is supposed to receive the intent. For sharing files, the data URI needs to be corresponding to the file that needs to be shared.

**If my question is not clear, please post a comment & I will clarify.**

**Edit :**

I also want to ask whether using sd card is the only way to share files when sending an Intent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to ask is whether it is possible to use URI permissions with an Intent when sending a Intent to a second app, instead of using in the app receiving the Intent ?

Yes.

> More specifically, can URI permissions be used when using APIs like startActivity or startService ?

Yes, though I have only tried it with `startActivity()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrating the use of `FileProvider` and granting a third-party permissions to view a PDF file served by that `FileProvider`.

> I also want to ask whether using sd card is the only way to share files when sending an Intent ?

Not only is it not the only way, it is not a recommended way. If your app has files to share with somebody else, use `FileProvider` or your own `ContentProvider` implementation.

Comment: Is it possible for the second app that received the Intent with URI permission to pass on the permission as an Intent to a third app ?

Comment: @Jake: "Is it possible for the second app that received the Intent with URI permission to pass on the permission as an Intent to a third app ?" -- no.

Comment: Could you please take a look at section 2.1 in this document : http://www.enck.org/pubs/nadkarni-ccs13.pdf . When searching I found this doc yesterday, and this where I got the picture to ask my doubt, thanks. In the given picture, how could DocuView share the file with WordToPDF ?

Comment: @Jake: It could make a local copy of the file, then share its own local copy. Or, it could require that the file be readable by all relevant parties in order for the flow to work.

Comment: " It could make a local copy of the file, then share its own local copy." -- does this imply DocuView might be using sd card for the local copy ?. " it could require that the file be readable by all relevant parties in order for the flow to work" -- does "It" refer to  Email or DocuView ? , and how is the readability of file by all relevant parties specified ? Thanks !!

Comment: @Jake: " does this imply DocuView might be using sd card for the local copy ?" -- no. It could serve it via a `FileProvider` from internal storage to other parties. "does "It" refer to Email or DocuView ?" -- DocuView. "and how is the readability of file by all relevant parties specified ?" -- I do not understand your question.

Comment: I tried the test for URI permissions using Broadcast. when setting a URI in the intent from the sender app, the receiving app's broadcast receiver never gets triggered ? I'm not sure if my observation is correct, could you please confirm this ? For service I know that it works

Comment: @Jake: "the receiving app's broadcast receiver never gets triggered ?" -- that will depend a lot on how you set up the receiver and the `Intent`. I suggest that you open a separate Stack Overflow question about that, providing the code that you are using for each side.